# DateFormater error only when running on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have a function to convert string to date format. This function works as expected on iOS 12 but on iOS 13. I get this error:

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Here is my code:

```swift
func ConvertDateAndTimeFormat2() {
     let timeDate = "2019-09-24 15:00:00 +0000"
     let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +zzzz"
     dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+3:00")
     var dateObj:Date!
     dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: timeDate)
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d, yyyy"
     dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+3:00")

     let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()

     timeFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +zzzz"
     timeFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+3:00")
     var timeObj:Date!
     timeObj = timeFormatter.date(from: timeDate)

     timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
     timeFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+3:00")
     let timef = "\(timeFormatter.string(from: timeObj!))"
     let Date = "\(dateFormatter.string(from: dateObj!))"
 }
```

Comment: But where exactly do you get the error? At `dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: timeDate)`?

Comment: Variable names should start with a lowercase letter and should never be the same as a built-in type (Date). Is this really the code that fails, kind of pointless with a void function that only assigns the result to local variables?

Answer (score 2):

Please change your dateformat and use "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" and try.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
```

For more details please visit https://nsdateformatter.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to convert string time which in 24 hours format (Ex 15:25:00 / HH:mm:ss) then enable your device 24-Hour Time option. It might solve the issue in IOS 13.3

You may find the option here

Settings -> General -> Date & Time

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with your code. There is no reason to create two `Date` objects from one string. Just parse the original string once. Then you can create your date string and time string with the desired formats from that one date.

You should also use the special locale of `en_US_POSIX` when parsing fixed format date strings. There is also no need to set a timezone when parsing the original date string. The string provides its own timezone. The `+0000` means it is UTC time.

You may not want to provide a timezone when converting the date to your final strings either. Most likely you want strings in the user's locale timezone, not some hardcoded timezone.

Here's your code cleaned up a lot:

```
func convertDateAndTimeFormat2() {
    let timeDate = "2019-09-24 15:00:00 +0000"

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    if let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: timeDate) {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d, yyyy"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+3:00") // Probably not needed

        let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        timeFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+3:00") // Probably not needed

        let timef = timeFormatter.string(from: dateObj)
        let datef = dateFormatter.string(from: dateObj)
        print("Date: \(datef), time: \(timef)")
    }
}

convertDateAndTimeFormat2()
```

Output:

> Date: Tuesday, Sep 24, 2019, time: 18:00

Comment: the code is much more complicated than this i just tried this code to create the problem with the simple code, but i will try you solution to my code, thanks :-),  tried to vote you but i get this msg "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."